# How to solve $a^bc^d = abcd$ where $ a, b, c,d \in $Z

Tags: number-theory

Is there a solution to this? notes that a, b, c, d are different integers.

I have tried to solve it with algebra and my equations are leading me in circles.

I know that 0 and 1 solve this.  Are there other integers?

Comment: $b=1, \; d=1 {}{}{} $

Comment: @WillJagy any others?

Comment: $a=b=c=d=2$ works

Comment: And $a=b=d=3$ with $c=1$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what you want, but $2^59^2=2592$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a prime $p$  that divides $a$.  How many factors of $p$ are on each side?